# Activity Is Taking Too Much Time To Load

Tags: android, android-studio, onitemclicklistener

I am a beginner at android. I have created a recyclerview which parses data from a JSON. I have set an onclick listener to all recyclerview item which opens new activity and show details of the recycler view item. My problem is when I click a recyclerview item it takes 4-5 seconds to load can I make this faster please help.

My Activity Code

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener{
    private RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "imageUrl";
    private ShimmerFrameLayout mShimmerViewContainer;
    Button sharebuttonz;
    File imagePathz;
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mShimmerViewContainer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());


        // Set the adapter here.
        // Use getActivity() instead of getContext()
        parseJson();
        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
        mExampleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Tab1.this);


      return rootView;
    }



    private void parseJson() {
        String url = "http://maranamassapp.cf/json_getdata.php";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject ser = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String creatorname = ser.getString("head");
                                String imageUrl = ser.getString("image");
                                String cat = ser.getString("content");
                                String postdate = ser.getString("weburl");
                                String dateall = ser.getString("date");
                                int type = ser.getInt("type");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, creatorname, cat, postdate, dateall,type));
                            }



                            // Just call notifyDataSetChanged here
                            mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
                            mShimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }


        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Intent detailintent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            ExampleItem clickeditem = mExampleList.get(position);
            detailintent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickeditem.getmDate());
            startActivity(detailintent);
    }
}
```

My Adapter Code

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private onItemClickListener mListener;


    public interface onItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewCat;
        public TextView mDateAll;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_cat);
            mDateAll = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_views);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: setup your adapter to work with a empty list then pars Json and then add json items to your empty list

Comment: No issue is visible in your code. over which environment you tested the application? Android Emulator? or physical device?

Comment: Your time is all going to be in the network request and parsing the result, mainly in the network request.  Not much you can do about that.

Comment: As far as I understand, you have issue about loading time for Detail Activity. So, you should post your Detail activity codes and xml layout. Clearly you have inflate performance issue. It can be also occur by slow emulators too. Did you try the app on real devices?

Answer (score 0):

Implement listener on `RecyclerView` instead of individual item. This is better as it avoids unnecessary `OnClickListener` creation.

As for the slow loading of activity, this seems to be layout optimization issue. As suggested by Oğuzhan Döngül, you should find out if problem persists on actual device. I would suggest reading [Improving Layout Performance](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/) nevertheless, they show many tricks which will be of great help.

Comment: iam trying it on a actual device still it is slow.

Comment: Then read the training article mentioned above. It helped me improve performance when I was a beginner.
Basically you need to lazily load the layout and keep the layout as flat as possible. You will understand these concepts from article.